# access denied connecting to mysql with yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, mamp

I get this error when trying to connect to my db with Yii

I am sure the password and permissions are correct. How do I track down the problem here?

I am running MAMP and the latest Yii.

```
CDbException

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'yii'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

/Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/gii/generators/model/ModelCode.php(54)

42         ));
43     }
44 
45     public function requiredTemplates()
46     {
47         return array(
48             'model.php',
49         );
50     }
51 
52     public function init()
53     {
54         if(Yii::app()->db===null)
55             throw new CHttpException(500,'An active "db" connection is required to run this generator.');
56         $this->tablePrefix=Yii::app()->db->tablePrefix;
57         parent::init();
58     }
59 
60     public function prepare()
61     {
62         if(($pos=strrpos($this->tableName,'.'))!==false)
63         {
64             $schema=substr($this->tableName,0,$pos);
65             $tableName=substr($this->tableName,$pos+1);
66         }
```

Comment: You're either using a bad username or a bad password from the host that's issuing the requests.  (MySQL user/password pairs can be host specific)...

Comment: your db connect information is not correct. check your config about DB information.

Comment: can you show the code in your db connection configuration array, in the myapp/protected/config/main.php file? Plus show the output of `mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;` ?

Answer (score 4):

In the file /protected/config/main.php look for the "components" block and update as needed:

```
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DBNAME',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'MYSQL_USER',
        'password' => 'MYSQL_PASS',
    ...
```

(change UC vals to your settings). And read [these pages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have entered your database info in the correct configuration file (in `/config`). Presumably Gii is using the `main.php` config file, so make sure you didn't set up the DB credentials in `console.php` or `test.php` by accident instead on `main.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the supplied credentials are correct, then the `yii` user must not have permission to connect from `localhost`.  MySQL authentication is done by username, password, and host, so it reads like one of those is incorrect.

Comment: How do I track that down in Yii. I have set up plenty of DB connection in MAMP with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mamp on a local machine make sure your username is set to 'root' and the password is set to 'root' in the main.php file. The default is to set password to null and this will cause the error above.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you  change the credentials in console.php ( yiic will not look for main.php , though it has the same thins repeated )

Answer (score 0):

Here I have working code:

OS Ubuntu:

```
<?php

return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=192.168.1.11;dbname=yiidemo',
'username' => 'yiidemo',
'password' => 'yiidemo!23',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Working for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
Solved it by:
Open file `yii/config/db.php`
and add your data for phpmyadmin (password&name).